# I can't get a result somewhere when drawing the cmd graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_cmd(table):
    y_ekseni = mutlak_magnitude
    x_ekseni = bp-rp

    plt.plot(x, y,  markersize=0.3, alpha=0.3)

    plt.xlim([0, 1.5])
    plt.ylim([14, 22])
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

    plt.ylabel('$Magnitude (g)$')
    plt.xlabel('$Color (g-i)$')
```

I want to get a cmd graph by putting bp-rp on the horizontal axis and g brightness on the vertical axis. But when I run these codes, I get neither error nor result.

Comment: Have you tried `plt.show()`?

Comment: how did you call the function?